# Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference (Add item to listview from other form)

Tags: vb.net, listview

i have a form called "store" and i want to add a listview item from other form called "Downloader", but when i put the code: `Store.ListViewExtended1.Items.Add(item)` give me that error called "Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference".

What i can do?

Comment: show more of that procedure.  we cant tell anything from one isolated line of code with no context.  in general you would be better off passing data to the other form and let it fiddle with its own controls

Comment: I will try to explain what I want do: I have a "listview1" in my form called "Store", now im other form called "Downloader" i want edit the "listview1" which is in another form. But I cant find a way to do it, because when i try to add a item using "Store.ListViewExtended1.Items.Add(item)" gives me a error.

Comment: `ListViewExtended1` sounds like a custom control.  edit your post to add *code* not more explanation - there is no context to know for sure what is wrong

Comment: ListViewExtended1 it's a simple "Listview"